# Doing MS in CS from low ranked university versus applying again next year?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I have done  my undergrad in electronics from India and want to do a masters in computer science. My initial goal was to do it from a good university but I got rejected from all the ones that I applied to, even though I have very good GRE scores but an average GPA (68% approx = 3.1) with no industry experience. I got acceptance from a university in TX that has no rank published on usnews rankings.

Should I accept going to low/no rank university now or should I try again next year?

Secondly, is it okay to request the university to defer the admission for a year so that I can apply for better universities next year? I think it's highly unlikely that the university will hold the spot for me for an year but still asking to get some advice. 
Thanks in advance for helping me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't rely only on a ranking to figure out if a particular university is the right place for you.  Here is what you can look at instead:

- course offerings at the candidate university
- schedule of classes for next fall and spring -- this is important, because some institutions list mouth-watering courses which are almost never offered in practice
- faculty profiles
- faculty publications
- opportunities for student research projects and collaboration with industry
- the institution's commitment to assisting students with their job search
- their calendar of events to see what sort of seminar talks and cultural events take place there
- their list of student clubs, to see if you will find like-minded souls there

Answer (score 2):

> (1) Should I accept going to low/no rank university now or should I try again next year?

You must go to USA first. The world is changing every now and then. You never know what will happen next year. You can have the Visa, go there, and, you will always have the opportunity to change your university.

> (2) is it okay to request the university to defer the admission for a year so that I can apply for better universities next year?

If the university has a provision to do so, they will. For example, I got acceptance from UCD, Dublin, Ireland. They have a provision to do so. So, I paid the registration fee and they reserved my acceptance for the next year. But, It is highly unlikely that I would go there.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things to be considered: 
Firstly, unlike India, where companies visit colleges and most of the recruitment takes place in campus; in the USA, recruitments are mostly off campus. So, if yoy are good enough to be in Google (say), you can get there irrespective of the rank of your grad school. 
On the other side, grad schools give you great connections. You are most likely to have people with great future in your connections if you end up at MIT or other high tier universities. And, trust me, that's an important thing.

I believe a lot of universities allow deferring the admit for an year. You can give it a shot.

But again, I also want you to be realistic on what you think of yourself. If you think you can make to a much better school, it would be worth waiting.

Decision lies in your hands!!!

Comment: _in the USA, recruitments are mostly off campus_ — Not necessarily.  Top CS departments in US all have thriving corporate-relations programs, with every major company you've heard of (and several smaller companies you haven't yet) visiting campus multiple times per year to recruit students.

Comment: You are right @JeffE. I belong to a different department and I tried to generalize it for all the departments.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day your knowledge matters, not what is written on paper.

Of course getting Degree from Indian Institute of Technology (for example, since you are probably from India) is only a guide for how competent you are.

In my life I have seen

- people from IIT who are doing excellent, such as founder of Sun Microsystems, Executive staff of Cisco
- CEO of Microsoft got education from ok school but he proved his competence with results
- people from IIT are in so-so jobs because their parents pressured them to attend but weren't interested, etc (this is common in Indian culture)
- people like Mittals and Ambanis who were nowhere near an IIT but look at them, they are top self-made billionaires from a India, a country where it is more difficult to achieve such status than say, USA

Although getting into a prestigious school is quite impressive at the end of the day you show the employer (and most importantly yourself)

how knowledgeable

how competent

how enthusiastic

you are about the subject.

I say go to this ordinary University for now and get an appreciation for what is being taught.

If you feel the courses are too slow, you can always transfer to more prestigious University.